# How to read the following "if" statement and what is the rule to determine the precedence in JAVA?

Tags: java, if-statement

I have just realised that I have problems with understanding one of the most basic principle in programming languages and that is how to figure out how an "if" statement will execute given some boolean values and operators like &, &&, |, || without enclosing them in brackets.

I was wondering if someone could show me ho to figure out how the JVM looks at the following "if" statement.

```
if( true || false & true && false | false ) ;
```

Im not interested in the resulting boolean value but rather how the above "if" statement would look like if enclosed in brackets.

Comment: For precedence, google for "Java operator precedence", there are a lot of links which tell you that

Comment: The JVM looks at the if statement like this: if(true OR ) then it ignores the rest because its always true.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The if statement above will stop evaluation once it encounters `true ||` and anything after that will be skipped as the `true`ness of `if-statement` is fulfilled.

The operator precedence order describes as `&&` precedes `||`, and hence you can devise the logic for your statement.

To simplify, your if-statement will be executed as below:

```
if ( true || ((false & true) && (false | false)) )
```

You can have more info on Operator Precedence table in Java here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: what if I say if( true || false || true && false || false ) how would id look like thanks.

Comment: Same. With 'or' if any of the expressions evaluate to true the answer is known, so everything else is skipped. With 'and' all expressions have to be evaluated until one is false

Answer (score 2):

[Java operator precedence rules](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) state following:

```
& precedes |
| precedes &&
&& precedes ||
```

Therefore, your if statement is evaluated like this:

```
1. if (true || false && false) // false & true = false
2. if (true || false)          // false | false = false
3. if (true)                   // true || false = true
```

You should also know that Java would stop evaluating your conditional expression after the step one since there is `true` OR something else. One `true` is enough to make this whole expression `true` since it's followed by the (logical) OR.

Answer (score 1):

In your example everything after

```
if( true ||
```

will be ignored, because in Java a boolean expression will terminate as soon as the result is known. And because `true || anything` is always `true`, the rest of the expression is not evaluated.

Comment: Just so he knows a term to look up... This is called Short Circuit Evaluation

Comment: Just a sidenote: It will stop evaluating after `true` only if you use the short-circuit OR `||` if you just use a `|` it will still evaluate the other half, the result will not be affected however.

Answer (score 1):

This is the same as this (I've added extra brackets to show precedence)

```
 if ( true || ((false & true) && (false | false)) )
```

See here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html for a table of operator precedence.

While it does work I would never use | or & (which are bitwise operators) on boolean values.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will ignore `false & true && false | false` and mark it as deadcode, because it cant be reach after `true ||`. But if the compiler didnt know the values at the compile time, it will work like this:

1. false & true -> `if(true || false && false | false)`
2. false | false -> `if(true || false && false)`
3. false && false -> `if(true || false)`
4. true || false -> `true`